# How do I access up-sell items' pricing levels in 3dcart?

Tags: shopping-cart

I've been tasked to work with a shopping cart site that uses 3dcart. The former developer looped through an item's up-sell items and printed them to the page. He was also using the 'DisplayText' feature to hide the real price of those items.

My question is this: how do I access the REAL pricing levels (not the text that overrides them) for each of those items and then print them to the page? For the main item, he simply did something like [price_7], however, I don't seem to have access to those variables in the up-sell item loop?

Answer (score -1):

This may be too simple but what if you just removed the [DisplayText] data annotations? That way you would be viewing the original price.

Comment: That would be way too simple, and it would be the correct way, but I've inherited this from someone who decided to make things as challenging as possible; it's all a hack and the owner insists that the hacks continue (and the annotations span thousands of items.)